# Is there a way to replace jinja2.ext.autoescape and jinja2.ext.with_ in Flask Babel?

Tags: flask, python-babel, flask-babel

I'm using Flask Babel for web translation:
When I write my config file like the following, it doesn't find any translations and the error is that jinja2.ext.autoescape and jinja2.ext.with_ are deprecated.
babel.cfg

```
[python: **.py]
[jinja2: **/templates/**.html]
extensions=jinja2.ext.autoescape,jinja2.ext.with_
```

If I remove the extensions line, it doesn't read the tags with underscore `_{{ "some text" }}`, only the `{{ get_text("some text")}}`

```
[python: **.py]
[jinja2: **/templates/**.html]
```

How can I configure the underscore tag like `_{{ "some text" }}`?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the documentation was outdated on the [Flask Babel](https://python-babel.github.io/flask-babel/#translating-applications) side, it is clearly mentioned in `Jinja` documentation that you don't need those extensions anymore, [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/extensions/#autoescape-extension) and [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/extensions/#with-statement).

Also you are misusing the shortcut `_` for `gettext`. Instead of `_{{ "some text" }}` you should be writing `{{ _("some text") }}`.